# ExcludeFromCodeCoverage not work with asp.net core 3.1 unit test project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, asp.net-core-3.1

```
using MyAPI.ShippingAddress.Operations;
using MyAPI.ShippingAddress.Request;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace MyAPI
{
    public class DependencyServiceFactory
    {
        [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
        public void Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

I created asp.net core 3.1 MS unit test project and everything work as expected but [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] not working. I need to remove this method from code coverage result

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I believe we need Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated, is that enough ?

Comment: Is excluding working for assembly or class [assembly: ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]

Answer (score 1):

Add CodeCoverage.runsettings file and configure it using test explore. CodeCoverage.runsettings file should be contain "System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute"

```
        <Attributes>
          <Exclude>                
            <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.DebuggerHiddenAttribute$</Attribute>
            <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
            <Attribute>^System\.Runtime\.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute$</Attribute>
            <Attribute>^System\.CodeDom\.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
            <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>
          </Exclude>
        </Attributes>
```